# Replacing placeholder values within a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Not sure why my code is not working because the code I took from below is working in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fFSYA/2/)

```js
String.prototype.interpolate = (function() {
  var re = /\[(.+?)\]/g;

  return function(o) {
    return this.replace(re, function(_, k) {
      return o[k];
    });
  }
}());

var _obj = {
  hey: 'Hey',
  what: 'world',
  when: 'today'
}

document.write(
  '[hey]-hey, I saved the [what] [when]!'.interpolate(_obj)
);
```

But my code below doesn't seem to be doing the same thing. It still has the bracket values **[NAME][ADDRESS][PHONE]** and not the replaced data values:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#goSearching').click(function () {
        var isNumber    = $.isNumeric($('#searchBox').val());
        var theSearch   = $('#searchBox').val();
        var theURL      = '';

        if (isNumber) {
            if (theSearch.length >= 10) {
                //Search by NPI#
                $('#titleOfSearchResult').html('P search results by NPI #:');
                theURL = 'http://zzzzz.com:151/P/GetNPI/';
            } else {
                //Search by P #
                $('#titleOfSearchResult').html('P search results by P #:');
                theURL = 'http://zzzzzz.com:151/P/GetNo/';
            }
        } else {
            //Search by P Name
            $('#titleOfSearchResult').html('P search results by P Name:');
            theURL = 'http://zzzzz.com:151/P/PName/';
        }

        $.ajax({
            url         : theURL + $('#searchBox').val() + '/',
            type        : 'GET',
            dataType    : 'xml',
            timeout     : 10000,
            cache       : false,
            crossDomain : true,
            success     : function (xmlResults) {
                console.log(xmlResults);
                var _htmlObj = {};

                $(xmlResults).find("P").each(function() {
                    _htmlObj = {
                        NAME    : $(this).find("pName").text(),
                        ADDRESS : $(this).find("pSpecialty").text(),
                        PHONE   : $(this).find("pUserid").text()
                    }

                    console.log($(this).find("pName").text());
                    console.log($(this).find("pSpecialty").text());
                    console.log($(this).find("pUserid").text());

                    $("#theResults").append(                        
                        '<p><strong>[NAME]</strong></p>' +
                        '<p>[ADDRESS]</p>' +
                        '<p>[PHONE]</p>' +
                        '<p>&nbsp;</p>'.interpolate(_htmlObj)           
                    );
                });
                },
            error       : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log("error: " + textStatus);
                }
        });
    });

    String.prototype.interpolate = (function () {
        var re = /\[(.+?)\]/g;

        return function (o) {
            return this.replace(re, function (_, k) {
                return o[k];
            });
        }
    }());
});
```

In the console it outputs the correct returned values but it **won't replace those values** with the placeholders **[NAME][ADDRESS][PHONE]**.

Any help to fix this issue would be great! Thanks!

Comment: You're using the `interpolate` function only in the last string

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a "real" templating system, such as Mustache, Handlebars, Jade, etc.? [There are tons to choose from...](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only calling `interpolate` on the last string

```
'<p><strong>[NAME]</strong></p>' +
'<p>[ADDRESS]</p>' +
'<p>[PHONE]</p>' +
'<p>&nbsp;</p>'.interpolate(_htmlObj)
```

Member access has a higher precedence than addition, so it needs to be:

```
('<p><strong>[NAME]</strong></p>' +
'<p>[ADDRESS]</p>' +
'<p>[PHONE]</p>' +
'<p>&nbsp;</p>').interpolate(_htmlObj)
```

Example from @TrueBlueAussie: [jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fFSYA/9](http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fFSYA/9)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks, I'll edit that into my answer